# Make a web componenet for an editor

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, ace-editor

I want to make a web component tag which consists of an editor with some added functionality. I am using ACE-JSON editor for now.

The main code is this, i do have some other js file with it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>JSONEditor</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsoneditor/5.32.5/jsoneditor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsoneditor/5.32.5/jsoneditor.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="worker.js"></script> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <style>
    html,
    body {
      font: 11pt sans-serif;
    }

    #jsoneditor {
      width: 700px;
      height: 600px;
    }

    #paste,
    #link,
    #file {
      margin-top: 25px;
      align-content: center;

    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 align="center">Load and save JSON documents</h1>
    <br><br><br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div id="jsoneditor"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-centered">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
              <option value="paste">paste json</option>
              <option value="file">Upload file</option>
              <option value="link">use link</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <p>
              Save a JSON document: <input type="button" id="saveDocument" value="Save" />
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div id="file" style="display: none;" class="col-sm col-centered">
              Load a JSON document: <input type="file" id="loadDocument" value="Load" />
              <button class="button" onclick="readFile()">LOAD JSON</button>
            </div>
            <div id="paste" style="display: none;" class="col-sm col-centered">
              <h3>Paste JSON data </h3>
              <textarea id="myText" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
              <button class="button" onclick="loadText()">LOAD JSON</button>
            </div>
            <div id="link" style="display: none;" class="col-sm col-centered">
              <h3>URL</h3>
              <input type="text" id="url">
              <button class="button" onclick="urlOnclick()">LOAD JSON</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  var options = {
    mode: 'tree',
    modes: ['code', 'form', 'text', 'tree', 'view'], // allowed modes
    onError: function (err) {
      alert(err.toString());
    },
    onModeChange: function (newMode, oldMode) {
      console.log('Mode switched from', oldMode, 'to', newMode);
    }
  };
  // create the editor
  var editor = new JSONEditor(document.getElementById('jsoneditor'), options);

  // Save a JSON document
  document.getElementById('saveDocument').onclick = function () {
    // Save Dialog
    fname = window.prompt("Save as...");

    // Check json extension in file name
    if (fname.indexOf(".") == -1) {
      fname = fname + ".json";
    } else {
      if (fname.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() == "json") {
        // Nothing to do
      } else {
        fname = fname.split('.')[0] + ".json";
      }
    }
    var blob = new Blob([editor.getText()], { type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8' });
    saveAs(blob, fname);
  };
</script>

</html>
```

How can I wrap it up in a web-component?
I tried it with JS but most of the tutorials were giving a small example of a simple tag. Most of the site was pointing towards polymer, but I didn't find any proper reference of what I want to do. 
please can you guide me or provide m some reference for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Third party libraries are usually not designed to be used with Web Components.

The problem you are going to run into is the use of jQuery and the jQuery plugins. When you create a Web Component you are creating a `#document-fragment` in a `#shadowRoot` component in the `shadowDOM`. What all that means is the standard DOM statements we use to select elements (`document.getElementById(...)`) won't work to select elements in the `shadowDOM`. That's because the `shadowDOM` is isolated from the root document. That's why you only find examples of simple tags.

JSONEditor, for example, [uses `document.createElement()` extensively](https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/search?q=document.createElement&unscoped_q=document.createElement).

I've converted your HTML/JS into a Web Component ***that won't work for the reasons stated above***. This will at least show you how to proceed with a more complex example.

As you can see in the sample below, external scripts and stylesheets are easily loaded into the component. Module `import` syntax can be used rather than creating script tags, but these libraries don't support that syntax.

Here are the key moving parts:

1. An ES6 Class representing the logic of the custom element
2. Your HTML has been placed within a `<template>` tag which is used to hold the DOM elements of the custom element
3. This statement that makes the custom element available for use:

   - `customElements.define('my-editor', MyEditor);`
4. Place `<my-editor></my-editor>` into the HTML file

Refer to the source code comments for details.

```js
class MyEditor extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.requiredScripts = [
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js',
      'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsoneditor/5.32.5/jsoneditor.js',
      'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js',
    ];
    // Grab a reference to the custom element
    let template = document.getElementById('my-custom-editor');
    // Get the #document-fragment
    let templateContent = template.content;
    // Place the template from the Web Component in to the active DOM
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
  }
  // lifecycle hook that fires when custom element is placed into DOM
  connectedCallback () {
    // load required external resources
    this.loadScripts(0);
  }
  
  loadScripts (idx) {
    const tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = this.requiredScripts[idx];
    tag.onload = () => {
      if (idx < this.requiredScripts.length - 1) {
        // when a script has finished, go get the next one
        this.loadScripts(++idx);
      } else {
        // Once all the script files are loaded, initialize the working parts of the component
        this.initEditor();
      }
    }
    tag.onload.bind(this);
    document.head.appendChild(tag);
  }
  
  initEditor () {
    // Need a reference to the #document-fragment
    // Every instance of "document" in this method has been replaced with "component"
    const component = document.getElementById('my-custom-editor').content;
    const options = {
      mode: 'tree',
      modes: ['code', 'form', 'text', 'tree', 'view'], // allowed modes
      onError: function (err) {
        alert(err.toString());
      },
      onModeChange: function (newMode, oldMode) {
        console.log('Mode switched from', oldMode, 'to', newMode);
      }
    };
    // create the editor IN THE compoent (rathar than the DOM)
    var editor = new JSONEditor(component.getElementById('jsoneditor'), options);
    component.getElementById('saveDocument').onclick = function () {
      fname = window.prompt("Save as...");
      if (fname.indexOf(".") == -1) {
        fname = fname + ".json";
      } else {
        if (fname.split('.').pop().toLowerCase() == "json") {
        } else {
          fname = fname.split('.')[0] + ".json";
        }
      }
      var blob = new Blob([editor.getText()], {
        type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
      });
      saveAs(blob, fname);
    };
    
  }
}

customElements.define('my-editor', MyEditor);
```

```css
html,
body {
    font: 11pt sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>JSONEditor</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="lib/MyEditor.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="app.js"></script> -->
    <!-- <script src="worker.js"></script> -->

</head>

<body>

<my-editor></my-editor>


<template id="my-custom-editor">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsoneditor/5.32.5/jsoneditor.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <style>
        #jsoneditor {
            width: 700px;
            height: 600px;
        }

        #paste,
        #link,
        #file {
            margin-top: 25px;
            align-content: center;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 align="center">Load and save JSON documents</h1>
        <br><br><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="jsoneditor"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-centered">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <select id="test" name="form_select" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                            <option value="paste">paste json</option>
                            <option value="file">Upload file</option>
                            <option value="link">use link</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <p>
                            Save a JSON document: <input type="button" id="saveDocument" value="Save"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <div id="file" style="display: none;" class="col-sm col-centered">
                            Load a JSON document: <input type="file" id="loadDocument" value="Load"/>
                            <button class="button" onclick="readFile()">LOAD JSON</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="paste" style="display: none;" class="col-sm col-centered">
                            <h3>Paste JSON data </h3>
                            <textarea id="myText" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
                            <button class="button" onclick="loadText()">LOAD JSON</button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="link" style="display: none;" class="col-sm col-centered">
                            <h3>URL</h3>
                            <input type="text" id="url">
                            <button class="button" onclick="urlOnclick()">LOAD JSON</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! 
See I wanted to make a utility which can fetch some JSON data and show this in an editor of a browser. This utility can be used in any project either angular, react, etc. 
CAN YOU SUGGEST SOME OTHER APPROACH THEN WEB COMPONENTS

Comment: `shadowDOM` is completely optional. Simply don't use it for this.

Comment: @connexo - not given the OP's use case.  this: _This utility can be used in any project_ requires isolation of DOM/JS/CSS, which requires `shadowDOM`

Comment: No, it does not require isolation via shadowDOM. What it does need is an isolated module bundle with the dependencies bundled without global scope pollution.

Comment: @connexo - my point being, that it isn't just the JavaScript that needs isolation. There is a great deal of HTML. Isolation includes HTML id attributes and CSS styles. One cannot accomplish that with module bundles.

Comment: we can use other editor also like moncao? can this be converted into a web componenet.

Comment: If you remove all the jQuery, Bootstrap and modify all the DOM manipulations. Sure.

Comment: @RandyCasburn sir, so this indirectly force us to make a new editor! do you suggest something else other than web component to make this as a general utility?

Comment: Editors utilities like [these](https://www.sitepoint.com/best-html-wysiwyg-plugins/) have been used as utilities for many years. Use those as they exist. OR, use Polymer. Most of these have been converted into web components already using Polymer: https://www.webcomponents.org/search/editor

Comment: @RandyCasburn sir, I have been working on this topic for last few days.
I have got some related work: https://github.com/Juicy/juicy-jsoneditor and https://www.npmjs.com/package/xtal-json-editor but I am not able to use them properly outside i tried each n everything, I am stuck from last few days.